# Import namespaced class as alias in output buffer PHP

Tags: php, object, namespaces

I'm using a php class with output buffering to create a view for my MVC app. I'm wondering if there is a way to import a namespace after ob_start() has run so that in my template file I can use the alias instead of having to write the entire class name with the namespace included ex.

```
        ob_start(); // Start buffering
        use Core\Options as Options;
        include_once 'template.php';
        $contents = ob_get_clean();
```

and then from within template.php I can use the following

```
        Options::get('option');
```

as opposed to having to use

```
        Core\Options::get('option');
```

which is how the app currently functions.

Comment: *"Output"* buffering and no, the `use` clause only imports the symbol into the **current** script

Comment: There is no such thing as "object buffering", and calling `ob_start()` makes no difference to how a PHP file is parsed; it just stops any output such as `echo` being sent straight to the browser.

Comment: @Phil and IMSoP sorry, its been a long day. I meant output buffering.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#example-273) states:

> Importing rules are per file basis, meaning included files will NOT inherit the parent file's importing rules.

This means you have to add those importing rules inside "template.php" instead.